# How to deal with a 'stolen' answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, attribution

This has happened to me a fair number of times...

- I check out a question that has been answered but not accepted because the answer was flat out incorrect
- I then provide an answer that does indeed solve the problem
- The person that answered before me then immediately edits their answer so it is now correct based off my answer
- The edited answer gets upvoted and or accepted when the original should have actually been downvoted or deleted.

I understand it's a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: The example that you provided doesn't seem compelling.  The original answer provided a detailed example, and it appears that he got one of the details wrong, which he *may* have realized after he saw your answer.  But there isn't much resemblance between the two answers otherwise.  Note that the poster of the original answer followed up with the OP.

Comment: Your example has no votes on either answer, only a small edit, and no "gratitude" from anyone.

Comment: It's clear in the comments the user tried the original answer and it didn't help. I answered "about an hour ago" and you can see the original answer was edited after I posted... And I saw it was wrong which is why I bothered to provide my own answer

Comment: It happens.  I'd let it go, and find some other questions to answer.

Comment: In know... it's just... frustrating. *shrug*

Comment: the meta question here is: are you getting karma for providing good answers, or are you providing good answers for getting karma?

Comment: To be fair, in the example you provided, the other answerer also lists himself as a "release engineer" at the company which provides the technology referenced.  It likely that he just forgot the one line, and your answer made that clear to him.  I don't think it's fair to say he "stole" your answer.  If he had a completely different answer, and then edited to reflect yours, then the circumstances and situation would be quite different.

Comment: "based off my answer" is silly and petty. If they literally copy your answer then they've stolen from you. If they use your answer in tandem with their answer and provide obviously most informative answer then they have succeeded in properly answering/refining their answer. This scenario sounds ideal to me, users rob from each other slowly until the *best* answer comes out in the end. If they aren't *only* providing your answer, and are using their own in tandem with yours it isn't "stealing".

Comment: Disagree with you Jhawins. I actually went to the mongodb Chef repo to check out the cookbook. If the original answerer had done that - he wouldn't have "guessed" at what was wrong, he would have known. I would have never been able to determine what the real answer was any other way. Really tho I wanted to post this question to encourage some discussion so this has been good.

Comment: It looks like you should have edited his answer rather than posted your own. It's not completely unreasonable that you posted yours, but then what do you expect him to do? Leave a wrong answer up? Delete it over a minor omission?

Comment: 1. If you have a problem with **me**, let's talk about it - all my contact info is in my profile. 2. Calling me a cheater/stealer behind my back is not how adults behave - again, all my contact info is in my profile. 3. I did not _steal_ any answers. I am sorry that you're frustrated, but that's simply not what happened in this situation. Again, if you would like to talk about it, all my contact information is in my profile.

Comment: And, for the record, the scenario that @Robert Harvey describes is, in fact, what did happen. I answer 10-15 Chef questions per day to try to **help** people and then I'm pointed at a thread like this where I'm being bashed behind my back. Not only is this incredibly discouraging and demoralizing, but it's also childish.

Comment: @sethvargo: There isn't much to see here.  The OP describes a pattern of this happening, but didn't single you out until I asked for specific examples.  Normally, we try not to single-out individuals, but it's very difficult to talk about these things without evaluating examples, and the community seems to be supporting you.  I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: I don't think an edit to correct the answer would have been accepted here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos and you say that why?

Comment: @sethvargo Because those edits are considered a "radical change" by most reviewers. Edits like that are usually only accepted if the the original poster accepts them before the queue reviewers get to reject them. When a post it incorrect in a non obvious way it's usually better to add a comment than to edit.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm the original answerer and I would have accepted it :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos, in relation to code modifications, if I know the language/technology I will evaluate and vote for the edit based off its merits. If I do not I will skip the review and leave it to those that do.

Comment: For those who want to hear my side of the story: https://sethvargo.com/stackoverflow-is-full-of-children/

Comment: @CodesInChaos Someone editing their _own_ answer (or question) is usually fine. It's _their_ reputation on the line, after all. Even major self-edits are usually OK; if you ever spot something (well, something problematic) then just Flag it. Remember, the focus is on the question and on getting the answer to the question; everything else is just to support that.

Comment: @sethvargo I read your post. It's hard to see how one bad experience constitutes "full of children." Now there's hyperbole on both sides. Thanks to the OP for starting an entertaining thread.

Comment: I agree with @Doug: the OP, seth and a third party have all reached for undiplomatic language (stolen, childish and pathetic respectively) that doesn't help mend fences. It would be better for all three to agree to disagree more positively if possible - no point making it worse.

Comment: @better - stolen answers does happen on Stack from time to time, though in my experience it is between different threads, and the low-rep poster tries to get a few points by copying-and-pasting someone else's answer. These usually get removed eventually. I don't think there is much evidence for this having "probably driven many users away".

Comment: @seth, following on from my comments yesterday. I sympathise with your feeling slighted by an accusation of 'stealing', but your blog post makes rather a mountain out of a molehill (and makes a number of guesses as to someone's motivation based on their voting records). I don't want to undermine your right to say what you want, but general readers to your site will not be able to tell who is right or wrong from your article (I'd say it is best deleted). If something like this happens again, just report to moderator, and move on `:)`.

Comment: @halfer I wrote the blog post to tell my side of the story. If you look at the information present in this thread and the original post, it looks like I am a bad guy. I wanted to tell my side of the story and present purely factual information. It's not about who is "right" or "wrong", it's about hearing both sides of the story and letting people make their judgement accordingly.

Comment: @seth, I appreciate you want to be heard, and I'm sympathetic to it. The initial accusation seems rather careless, especially given your good reputation. However in my experience, excessive analysis of a he-said-she-said ding-dong isn't likely to be fruitful, and perhaps makes you seem inclined towards over-reaction. I suspect most of the readers of that article won't have seen either of the Stack Overflow pages that gave rise to it. Anyway, just my small reflections upon it. Have a great day/evening!

Comment: (FWIW I've had all manner of abuse from help vampires on the main site, and despite my best intentions in the PHP tag to edit posts into shape and advise on making questions answerable, sometimes a report to mod is the best approach. This is often accompanied by my resisting the urge to add something unpleasant to someone who bloomin' well deserves it. I generally succeed in that endeavour, since I know that ill-motivated people rarely last long on Stack Overflow, and they get their comeuppance in the end).

Comment: This question should be re-opened based on the close reason *"This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange"* is not applicable.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.  "What does the newbie understand" is a very important part of your answer.  The other guy just did that better than you did, he picked up on the OP using config instead of code.

The right way to go about is to post *both* answers.  I usually start with the "push this button to solve your problem", what the OP actually wants.  He doesn't care to learn anything, typically, he just wants to move on with his day.  Maybe he'll try to RTFM the second time.  Then I *also* post the "what is really going on here" explanation, what everybody else wants to learn something they didn't know before.  You only get upvotes for that part.

Comment: Absolutely, the unfortunate truth is that people aren't here primarily to learn.

Comment: Sounds like you are still missing the message.  Questioners are but a small cog in the SO wheel, they constitute a fraction of a percent of the site traffic.  For every 1 questioner that reads your answer, there are easily 8 SO users that *are* here to learn something new.  In turn greatly outnumbered by the googlers, but they rarely interact.  Otherwise the motivator behind the comments of old, like "What have you tried?"  A question that doesn't help anybody learn something new is useless.  Best to not waste your free time on them.

Comment: I like your second paragraph, because often I see a question I could answer, check out the correct hand fed answer, and move on. But on occasion, if I go "huh, that's interesting" from part of an explanation I will upvote.

Answer (score 44):

I am the original poster. After reviewing the edit history, it is apparent that @better_use_mkstemp spotted the error first and gave the correct solution. I selected his answer and gave kudos also to @sethvargo for his effort on followup. I hope the case is now settled, I highly appreciate Stack Overflow as I could not get faster replies anywhere else.

Comment: Kudos to you too. You seem to be the only party involved with a level head with regard to this "issue".

Comment: In retrospective I think the important part here is that if taking information from somewhere else in the same question giving credit should always be obligatory. That way one can avoid any awkward situation right away always. :)

Answer (score 23):

> I saw it was wrong which is why I bothered to provide my own answer

### You're doing it wrong

If an existing answer contains a mistake which, in context, is nothing more than a typo - appropriate action is to write a comment notifying the author of the flaw or just suggest an edit to the answer, *not* to write another answer.

It's inappropriate to post an answer which is not substantially different to an existing answer and then complain when the earlier answerer realizes the mistake and corrects it (which can very easily happen without having seen or even know that another answer exists).

### But what if my answer really is copied?

If an answer really is a plagiarized copy of an existing answer, flag it:

[image: This is a word-for-word copy of another answer: link-to-existing-answer]

Be aware that it must be a *copy* of an existing answer (or very close to it) to be considered a copy - expressing the same answer with different words is not the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

If the two edits occurred five minutes apart so that you have an edit history, and it's clear in the edit history of their answer that they corrected theirs to match yours, flag the answer and ask a moderator to look at it.

Comment: I think that the correct behavior should have been down-voting it BEFORE the edit as it was an incorrect answer, but not after. Voting down a correct answer doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: @javi: You might see it as pretending you haven't seen the answer ;)

Comment: @javi Downvotes can also serve to discourage unwanted behaviour (but you should probably provide some explanation using comments, as others may just upvote it to reverse the downvote on the now-correct answer, and then you're the only one that loses).

Comment: Also comment on why it is incorrect. That leaves an audit trail of your contribution.

Comment: If the answer is wrong, then downvote. The correct attitude is that it is actually encouraged that you correct your answer based on other answers, even cutting and pasting from such answers to yours, the net result is that your answer becomes more pertinent and useful. Do not be a rep-whore moaning about rep if your contribution is actually used somewhere, this whole site is based on altruism and pay-it-forward ...

Answer (score 6):

Bear with me on this answer, there's a point...

One thing I do with some frequency on SO is post follow-up answers to questions that *already have an accepted answer*.  In some cases the question is more than a year old.

The reason I do this typically is because I had a problem, found the closest match to a solution (that wasn't quite enough), and then solved the problem myself.  I post a follow up answer for two reasons, 1) it helps me record what I did in case I ever encounter the problem again, and 2) it can help other people who have the same problem in the future.

If you do this a few times you'll find that people will randomly come by and upvote your answers (I've gotten quite a few points this way)!  What's more you might get a Tumbleweed or Necromancer badge which is kind of fun.  But best of all you'll absolutely stop caring whether or not someone comes in and steals your thunder, because there was no thunder to steal to begin with.

Give it a try!  You may find as I have your overall experience on SO is more positive and rewarding.

Comment: Many is the time I've found an answer through after-answers such as this, especially in rapidly changing areas. Thanks for doing it.

Comment: Upvotes on a better solution/answer to an old question seldom happen around here in my experience. I actually think this is a big problem on SO/SE-style sites.

Comment: I posted http://stackoverflow.com/a/11068356/312594 two years after the original question.  It currently has 17 upvotes and the accepted answer has 6.  If you post a useful answer it will get upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to consider that for a lot of questions like the one you linked to as an example, the answer is not subjective -- there's something wrong in the posted code, and one thing will make it right. Sure, there could be cases out there where someone plagiarizes another answer, and with an answer that involves a lot more written out explanation, it would be a lot easier to make a case in scenarios where someone has clearly derived their updated answer from yours. But with an answer like this that is small, succinct and just either right or wrong, does the person who posted the answer first lose the right to edit their answer if it isn't correct, just because another answer has been posted after?

It can feel annoying to post a good answer and have someone else's be accepted (which it wasn't even in the example case), but it's important to remember that the end goal of all of this is to help people who need help. If you aren't being full-on plagiarized, then there's always going to be some things that you just have to let go.

Answer (score 5):

First, I completely understand your frustration.  In the example you gave, the OP didn't see the timing of the edit and made a comment to your answer giving more credit to the other answer.  That's a good opportunity to explain to a new user that you can actually see the edit history.

SO is about creating a living knowledge base, that's why you can not only edit your own answers, but other people's answers too.  So if you seen an answer that needs improving, edit it.  If you see an answer that is wrong, down vote and then answer.

In the example that you give, I think the best thing would have been to edit the first answer, fix the mistake and then add then other information from your answer.  This would have resulted in a correct answer with two different ways to solve a problem.  Overall it would be much better quality.

Answer (score 0):

Some people simply do not play nice. They will even "cheat" to earn reputation.

I would say you look at the end product. If you think their answer is useful after the change, then the goal is reached. The question is answered, future visitors will find what they need. If their answer turns out to be more popular than yours, and the answers contain the same information, you can even think about deleting yours.

If you feel attached to your answer, you can still do what Robert says.

Comment: No don't do what Robert says - read my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I look at other peoples answers alongside my own. I am not ashamed to admit that they have often considered things that I haven't and amend my answer accordingly. Normally I put an update message to credit the fact that I have "borrowed" part of my answer from someone else, but occasionally I forget. I do think it is not acceptable however to steal someone else's answer in its entirety - if I find my answer is that much worse than someone elses I normally have the grace to either delete my own answer or amend it and state that another answer is better than my proposed solution.