# Feeling unwanted in SO community

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have lately tried to be more active on StackOverflow but it seems that low-rep users are punished for what they do.

Two examples I have:

- A person was asking a question about databases and there were NN-k rep users downvoting his question because "he should've used the right type from the start". It turned out the user had no choice but to use the DB in it's current state. Their "-1 because" comments were heavily upvoted.
- I answered a question with an almost identical answer than the high-rep user, and 5 minutes earlier. The OP even acknowledged my answer but still accepted the high-rep users answer.

I understand of course that this might have been simply because my answer was worse, but I can't help thinking that high-rep users "have it better" in the SO community. I'm a member for 4½ years and feel like SO has changed for the worse.

For me personally this problem is most apparent when I try to do wiki-style edits. I feel like I can't participate in the community because I can't do this or that (not enough points!). Sure, I've not asked questions or answered many, but SO has been part of my professional life for years now.

Comment: You can't know that the question was downvoted just because someone was using a different DB type than they should have.  Just because there were comments on a question saying he should use the proper DB type and downvotes on the post doesn't mean the two are correlated.  It's much more likely that that problem is an a problem that people felt worth pointing out, but that the issues warranting a downvote on the question were different.  Without seeing the question, we can only guess though.  As for the second point, as you said, it seems likely that the other answer is simply better.

Comment: I fail to understand how the first provided example supports your case. That question has no downvotes and Oded makes a valid comment. The OP could have updated his question with the information he provided in a comment. In the second case the OP was kind enough to expain why he chooses Martijns answer over yours while both answers were correct. You might have a point but your question could use better evidence.

Comment: Indeed - your idea of "almost identical answers" is certainly not the same as mine. Detailed explanations are important - there's a massive difference between "try this" and "This is why it's currently failing; instead, try this, which should work because of this..."

Comment: @JonSkeet I kinda thought the user had a "brainfart" and put login details into the header, and so just needed a quick "try this"... But you're all right, I am probably in the wrong here.

Comment: I added an answer because there was one incorrect answer (now deleted), and one answer that did not explain what the OP was doing wrong (yours). It is important not only to give someone the correct code (a fish), but also to show them how to not make the same mistake in the future (how to fish). My answer was only related to yours in that we both swapped `headers` for `data`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right. But it still stands that downvoting an asnwer for me is a bigger thing than for you. When I was on the 500 edge, I lost a privelege just because I downvoted a bad asnwer. The point I am trying to make is that maybe SO should move towards wiki-style editing, where users can fix stuff, even if they don't dedicate their life to SO.

Comment: on you second point, are you referring to [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260149/python-requests-session-login-cookies/24260465#24260465)?

Comment: @data: We *already* support wiki-style editing; up to 2k points you can submit edit suggestions, after that you can edit at will.

Comment: @data: note that I was a semi-active low-rep user for a few years before I became properly active: http://stackexchange.com/users/35417/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation. I am still a low-rep semi-active user on several other SE sites. Downvoting an answer is still *just 1 point*, don't be so afraid of that. I find that for fresh bad answers, 9 out of 10 times the post is deleted or improved, after which you get your point back or you can alter your vote.

Comment: @SamIam I think they *are* referring to that question. I'm not entirely sure *why* though, since they got a pretty satisfactory answer (in my mind, at least) from the person who asked it as to why they accepted Martijn's answer instead.

Comment: [You are doing it wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258562/17034).

Comment: -1 because you didn't give links to the questions that you're talking about.

Comment: -1 because of your rep. Just kidding, but seriously, I think I was treated pretty fair as a low rep user. I did this by (stay with me here) reading **all** of the help center before posting and reading through other posts by high rep users and learning how to conduct myself on the site, and by searching before posting. By looking at many questions/answers, a lot of low rep users obviously don't do those things.

Comment: OP, "try this" followed by a code dump is never a good answer. It might be a tolerable (== not downvote-worthy) answer if it solves the problem, but without any explanation of what caused the problem it will never be good. The only exception to this is if the code is so heavily commented that it serves as an easily parseable explanation on its own. StackOverflow is not about providing a quick fix for the asker, but about creating a reference of programming problems and solutions, and good solutions should of course include an explanation to serve as a good reference.

Answer (score 38):

As you probably already know, Stack Overflow has its share of users that post... well, junk.  That junk currently appears to be coming from:

1. Users who have very little experience in programming, and don't understand that you need a basic working knowledge and vocabulary in order to interact meaningfully with an experienced programmer.
2. Users who lack communication skills and social mores.  This includes many users for whom English is a second language, and many users who are very young.
3. Users who have a sense of entitlement, who want you to do their work for them, and treat Stack Overflow as a vending machine.
4. Users who don't read the manual first, perform some basic troubleshooting first, or put enough information into their question to make it answerable.
5. Users who come from forum environments, learned everything they know about interacting online in forums, and think they can do all the same things here (they can't).

In order for questions and answers to be useful to others, they need to be in clearly-written English, using the vocabulary of programmers, in an environment of professionalism.  None of the above bullets are compatible with that goal.

From my personal vantage point, I don't see low-rep users as being unduly singled-out.  Low-rep users *appear* to be singled out, because most of the problems I've described above come from low-rep users.  In general:

1. Low-rep users tend to *ask questions too early.*  They don't understand yet that they need to *earn the privilege of being mentored,* by doing their homework first and demonstrating that they are teachable.  This isn't a Stack Overflow peculiarity; it's true of every profession.
2. High-rep users are tired.  We do our best to keep the site clean, but we're greatly outnumbered by those who don't care about all of the above, and just want what they want, whatever that is.

So maybe you can understand now why we get a bit crotchety sometimes when it appears that someone is not "getting it."

Comment: Indeed; when you present it this way, the basic logic is clear. a) All askers of bad questions are not welcome. b) Many askers of bad questions are low-rep users. Or b') Most low-rep users are askers of bad questions. From these _it does not follow_ that c) All low-rep users are not welcome.

Comment: But that's the thing - "Low-rep users tend to ask questions too early" - I never got that feeling off. If you look at my profile I still have 0 questions asked - all because I never feel "worthy" of asking a question. I probably am putting in too much thought into rep, but as a contributor to wikipedia, for example, the neutrality just is not there. Ideally questions wouldn't have up/downvotes and answers were either edited to perfection by the community or deleted (because they were not an answer). There should be no popularity contest, which does exist in SO, sadly, in my opinion.

Comment: @data: There's too much junk to edit every bad question into shape.  We simply do not have the time, and we're not mind-readers.  It's not about popularity at all; it's about quality.  If you want to know what quality looks like, review several posts that Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert have made.  They don't have high rep because they are popular; they have high rep because they write quality posts.

Comment: @data You don't need to be "worthy" to write a question. You just need to write a worthwhile question. The sad thing about SO right now is there's a real risk that your good question won't get seen by the right person, because it's lost in a sea of bad questions. Of course, most of the good questions about established technologies, have already been asked and have answers -- which is how SO should be.

Answer (score 8):

As a semi-active low-rep user, I disagree.

If you're in it for the rep, it's always going to feel like you're at a disadvantage, time is against you. I personally feel I'm judged on what I say / how I act. If I say something dumb / wrong, it will get downvotes, and rightfully so, similarly, if I ask a question which isn't on topic, or shows no research, it will get downvotes.

If I answer a question, but I don't add as much detail as somebody else, it won't necessarily get downvotes, but it is unlikely to get more upvotes than an answer with much more detail.

Your rep/time on the site has nothing to do with how people vote, it's what you post<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sub>*Of course there are exceptions to this, revenge votes or whatever, but life goes on.</sub>

Comment: Note that it's extremely difficult to actually affect someone's reputation through "revenge votes". There is a (daily?) process that actively searches out for instances of serial voting and reverses the reputation loss (or gain), so actively trying to downvote a bunch of someone else's posts is effectively useless.

Comment: Serial voting and revenge voting can be two different things, but it is worth noting serial voting is often reversed automatically.

Comment: @Joe Cup's point stands though.  Even if such voting isn't reversed, it won't be able to be enough to meaningfully lower someone else's reputation.  In order to be enough to be really significant, it'd be reversed, so the only stuff that isn't reversed is stuff that just doesn't have a big impact.

Comment: @Servy I agree completely, I'm not disagreeing with his point at all.

Answer (score 4):

> A person was asking a question about databases and there were NNk rep users downvoting his question because "he should've used the right type from the start". It turned out the user had no choice but to use the DB in it's current state.

An asker's constraints do not automatically create an obligation on answerers. Answerers share their knowledge for free, and if they don't want to facilitate things they consider bad practices (insisting on using obsolete, unsafe MySQL interfaces in PHP and writing C in C++ come to mind), that's their prerogative.

If you want someone who will do what you tell them to do, pay for a consultant.

Comment: Aside from that, even if the person who asks the question has a highly unusual situation that may require the rules of good design to be broken, *most future Googlers will not*. Best not to mislead these people with low-quality hacks masquerading as good answers.